# How to install Cuda 7 with 349 drivers?

Tags: nvidia, cuda

I have been using the mamarley ppa, and recently support for nvidia 346 was stopped, so I switched to 349. Unfortunately, when I tried to install cuda, it removes nvidia 349 and reinstalls the older 346. Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: Exactly what command are you running to install the .deb with 349 drivers?

Comment: @MartinArjovsky I am using the method shown here: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/#runfile but this and any method replaces my 349 drivers. The solution appears to be a flag after the run command but those haven't worked, as it appears to function properly but programs cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

Download the relevant run file from [Nvidia](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). Run with `--kernel-module-only` flag.

Comment: I'm getting "Unknown option: kernel-module-only" when I run this

Comment: I had a look and they have taken --kernel-module-only out, try with '--toolkit' and '--samples'

Comment: Hi, I have done this and it seems to have installed, but I cannot access it in the program Blender